# JSF rich:tree selectionListener

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am new at using rich:tree component. When I have 3 nodes my `selectionChangeListener` method is correctly invoked. However, when the innermost node is selected  empty argument ( `selectionChangeEvent.getNewSelection()`) is sent to `selectionChangeListener`method.

I cannot find the problem.

```
<h:panelGrid>
            <rich:tree nodeType="#{node.type}" value="#{kampusBean.mevcutkampus.rootnodes}" var="node" 
                       selectionChangeListener="#{kampusBean.mevcutkampus.selectionChanged}" 
                       toggleType="client" selectionType="ajax" render="paftapanel">
                <rich:treeNode type="Node1">
                    #{node.name}
                </rich:treeNode>
                <rich:treeNode type="Node2">
                    #{node.name}
                </rich:treeNode>
                <rich:treeNode type="Node3">
                    #{node.name}
                </rich:treeNode>
                <rich:treeNode type="Node4">
                    #{node.name}
                </rich:treeNode>
            </rich:tree>
            <a4j:commandButton image="/resources/add.png" action="#{kampusBean.mevcutkampus.addNode1()}"
                               render="paftapanel"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Selection listener method:

```
public void selectionChanged(TreeSelectionChangeEvent selectionChangeEvent) {

    List<Object> selection = new ArrayList<Object>(selectionChangeEvent.getNewSelection());
    if (selection == null || selection.isEmpty()) {
        return; //when node4 is selected, selection is empty and always returns. 
    }
    Object currentSelectionKey = selection.get(0);
    AbstractTree tree = (AbstractTree) selectionChangeEvent.getSource();

    Object storedKey = tree.getRowKey();
    tree.setRowKey(currentSelectionKey);
    mevcutSecim = (TreeNodeLevel) tree.getRowData();
    tree.setRowKey(storedKey);
}
```

Comment: If the selection is empty it means the tree couldn't find the the node based on the id it received. It might be caused by your data model or there is a bug, hard to say without debugging it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That node is dynamically created with an a4j:commanbutton action. Can this cause the problem?

Comment: When I create the nodes statistically, nothing changes. Only node4 has problem. Other nodes work perfect.